# scss-bundle error: @use rules must be written before any other rules

Tags: sass

I have a file structure like this:

```
---- _base-map.scss
---- _child-map-1.scss
---- _child-map-2.scss
---- _child-map-3.scss
styles.scss
```

styles.scss imports all the child map files:

```
@import './base-map';
@import './child-map-1';
@import './child-map-2';
@import './child-map-3';
```

So far so good.

_base-map.scss :

```
$base-map : (
    "font-size"                 : 1.3rem,
    "border-radius"             : 0.4rem,
    // ...
);
```

In order to use "map.merge", @use "sass:map" has to be included:

_child-map-1.scss :

```
@use "sass:map";
$child-map-1 : map.merge(
    $base-map,
    (
            "font-size"                 : 2rem,
            "border-radius"             : 0.5rem,
    // ...
    )
);
```

But when I try to bundle the files with scss-bundle I get this error :

```
[17:22:37] erro: There is an error in your styles:
[17:22:37] erro: @use rules must be written before any other rules.
[17:22:37] erro:     ╷
[17:22:37] erro: 838 │ @use "sass:map";
[17:22:37] erro:     │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[17:22:37] erro:     ╵
[17:22:37] erro:   stdin 838:1  root stylesheet on line (838, 1)
```

When I don't include @use "sass:map" the scss compiler complains about map.merge.

What's the right way to solve this?

Comment: Since you are using `@import` simply use `map-merge()` (which doesn't require `@use`).

Comment: That solved it. Thanks!!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had to change "map.merge" to "map-merge" to make it work.

Thanks to @Arkellys.

HTH someone.

Comment: This is not a solution but a workaround

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete theme-style.scss
2. Open angular.json file and look for-
   architect-
   build-
   styles-
   remove this line- "src/custom-theme.scss"

You are all-set!

Answer (score 0):

I'll post how I solved this error since the accepted answer was not ideal.
The goal is to move away away from `map-get` and use the recommended `map.get` function.

There's an `Index.scss` file that looked like this which would produce the error above.

```css
@use "sass:map";
@import "../../file1.scss";
@import "../../file2.scss";

$width: 98px;
.someClassName {
  z-index: map.get($someValue, 'someString');
}
```

To solve the issue the content of the SCSS file was mostly moved to `subfile.scss`. In that subfile the `@use "sass:map"` works without issues. Most likely since the `@imports` are not in that file.

---

Working example:

```css
@import "../../file1.scss";
@import "../../file2.scss";
@import "./subfile";
```

The subfile where `@use: "sass:map"` is.

```css
/* subfile.scss */

@use "sass:map"

$width: 98px;
.someClassName {
  z-index: map.get($someValue, 'someString');
}
```

Note: [We should be moving away from @import](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import/).